# <body> has no width

Tags: jquery, html, css, document-body

I am creating a webpage that has an "all-in-one" layout. When you click the links in the sidebar, the main content slides right and gets replaces by another content block that slides in from the right. I have done this many times but in some cases this weird thing happens where it's like `<body>` has no width. 
The page loads correctly and then as soon as it's fully loaded, the width of the `<body>` disappears.

If I inspect element on the page and toggle the `left` property in `.slide` off and then on, it works perfectly. 

It should also be noted that I hadn't made any alterations to the page when this started happening. I just refreshed and it suddenly broke.

I also took away the jQuery and the problem persisted.

Here is the relevant code:

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" slide="wrapper" class="toggle">home</a>
    <li><a href="#" slide="feedback" class="toggle">feedback</a>
    <li><a href="#" slide="request" class="toggle">request</a>
</ul>
<div id="request" class="slide">
    ...
</div>
<div id="feedback" class="slide">
    ...
</div>
<div id="wrapper" class="slide active">
    <div id="posts">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    padding:70px 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
#posts {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:430px;
}
#feedback, #request {
    background:#fafafa;
    width:430px;
    padding:25px;
    border:5px solid #fafafa;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    margin-left:calc(50% - 215px);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    max-height:calc(100vh - 140px);
    overflow:auto;
}
.slide {
    left:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.active {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.slide').removeClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr("slide");
    $('#'+id).addClass('active');
});
```

What it looks like:
[image: what it looks like]

What it should look like:
[image: what it should look like]

[Link to the page](http://bannersbyrehticent-test.tumblr.com/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `body{width:100%;}` or even `body{width:100%!important;}`?

Comment: I just tried `body{width:100%!important;}`. It now loads fine, then does the weird 0 width thing, and then when the page has finished loading, snaps back to what it should be.
edit: It's back to initial odd behaviour.

Comment: So after loading the page does look how you want it to look, it is just during the loading that it does not look right

Comment: Your `.slide` class has `left: 100%`, this should be removed. (Why is it there anyway?)

Comment: @CasperS It's back to how it was when I first asked the problem. @goombah No, `.slide` needs `left:100%` as that's what positions all the slides off the page. `.active` overwrites this for the active slide with `left:0`

Comment: Could you hide the page until it's loaded right and then display it?

Comment: @CasperS It doesn't load right. My first reply to you it loaded weirdly and then ended up correct, but if you see my edit, this stopped happening and it's back to it's initial odd behaviour.

Comment: It seems your `body` element contains only children which have `position: absolute;` which removes these element from the *document flow*. This results in the body collapsing since it does not have any content that would cause it to have non-zero dimensions.

Comment: @connexo the problem still persists when `#wrapper` is changed to be part of the document flow.

Comment: play with: "position: absolute;" on #feedback and #request

Comment: @Seabizkit I added `position:fixed` to them and it solved my issue. Do you know why that might be? Also can you post it as an answer so I can accept it please. Thank you

Comment: You fixed it yourself, post and accept your own answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `#feedback` and `#request` from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` seemed to solve the issue.